# Encoding elements within a column or row vector MATLAB

Tags: matlab, encoding

Write a function encodedgt that takes as input a column or row vector with integer entries and produces as output a row vector where each integer is encoded according to the following table

Integer Encoding 
0     0 0 0 1 1 0 1
1     0 0 1 1 0 0 1
2     0 0 1 0 0 1 1
3     0 1 1 1 1 0 1 ... etc.

and the rule encodedgt(x) = 1 - encodedgt(-(x+1)) when x < 0.

For example,

> > encodedgt([1 12 -3])
> >
> > [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0]

---

So I already wrote a script that works fine with positive numbers which is the following...

> > function x = encodedgt(x)
> >
> > enc = {0, '0 0 0 1 1 0 1'; 1 , '0 0 1 1 0 0 1'; 2, '0 0 1 0 0 1 1';...
> >         3, '0 1 1 1 1 0 1'; 4, '0 1 0 0 0 1 1'; 5, '0 1 1 0 0 0 1'; 6, ...
> >         '0 1 0 1 1 1 1'; 7, '0 1 1 1 0 1 1'; 7, '0 1 1 1 0 1 1'; 8, ...
> >         '0 1 1 0 1 1 1'; 9, '0 0 0 1 0 1 1'; 10, '0 0 0 0 1 0 1'; 11, ...
> >         '1 0 1 0 0 0 0'; 12, '0 1 0 1 0'};
> >
> > y = str2num(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(v)enc{find([enc{:, 1}]) == v, 2}', x(:), 'UniformOutput',0)))'
> >
> > end

HOWEVER, I'm not entirely sure how to get it to work with negative numbers. As the question tells me, encodedgt(x) = 1 - encodedgt(-(x+1)) when x < 0. So I thought about using an if statement but er it's not coming out exactly to plan. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: You should start by describing what is it you have tried

Comment: do you want to use a look up table or do apply a formula to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very specific so it is hard to know exactly what you need.  Some tools you will need:

- how to concatenate vectors.  For this, use cat or just the following approach:

  > > sequence=[0 0 1 1 0 0 1];
  > >     sequence=[sequence [0 0 1 0 0 1 1]]
  > >
  > > sequence = 0     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     1
- how to iterate through a vector.  For this, use for:

  > function(x)
  >     for i=x
  >       % do what you need, like a lookup of i to get it's encoded vector
  >     end